# outer join in mysql on tables created in subqueries

Tags: mysql, full-outer-join

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) shows how to do outer join in mysql, but can I do a full outer join between  sub-queries as tables without having to re-execute the sub-queries for each half of the union?

Comment: Can you show those queries, the table structure, and a textual description of the desired result. There may be another solution.

Comment: I did find another way, but I was curious if there was a way to select into tables which could be reused for that particular type of join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, but the query optimizer may be smart enough to keep the performance hit to a minimum.